# I need NBSP Entities to make space inbetween li tags but when the underline from the hover state is applied it extends out where the space is

Tags: html, css

Before anything heres the html and css

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Language And Resource Imports -->
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Doppio+One|Rajdhani|Quicksand|Raleway&effect=shadow-mutliple|outline">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
<script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>JF Web | Page 1</title>
</head>

<header>
  <div id="titlebar">
    <div id="logotext">
      <h1>JF Web &copy;</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul id="navbar" class="cf">
        <li><a href="Index.html" class="active">&nbsp;&nbsp;Page 1&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="">&nbsp;&nbsp;Page 2&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="">&nbsp;&nbsp;Page 3&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<body onload="mainClock()">
<span id="clock"></span>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#logotext {
  font-family: 'Doppio one';
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  position: relative;
  top: 25.5px;
}

.cf {
  clear: both;
}

#navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;

}

#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;

}

#navbar a:hover {
  color: rgb(204, 153, 0);
  text-decoration: underline;

}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
}

#clock {
  font-family: Rajdhani;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}



#titlebar {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #414a4c;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

SO as u can see the navigation bar uses an inline unordered list and so to put a space inbetween the anchor texts ive used two nbsp entities on either side of the anchor text but when the hover state is active and the underline is applied it underlines the nbsp as well 
[NBSP Underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Pdg.png)

Any help would be much appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `&nbsp;`, and replace with CSS `padding` on the `<a>` tags:

```
#navbar a {
  padding: 0 .5em;
}
```

```css
#logotext {
  font-family: 'Doppio one';
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  position: relative;
  top: 25.5px;
}

.cf {
  clear: both;
}

#navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;

}

#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 .5em; /* Padding can replace spaces*/

}

#navbar a:hover {
  color: rgb(204, 153, 0);
  text-decoration: underline;

}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
}

#clock {
  font-family: Rajdhani;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}



#titlebar {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #414a4c;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Language And Resource Imports -->
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Doppio+One|Rajdhani|Quicksand|Raleway&effect=shadow-mutliple|outline">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
<script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>JF Web | Page 1</title>
</head>

<header>
  <div id="titlebar">
    <div id="logotext">
      <h1>JF Web &copy;</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul id="navbar" class="cf">
        <li><a href="Index.html" class="active">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<body onload="mainClock()">
<span id="clock"></span>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "nbsp" and add a margin,
See below example

```css
#logotext {
  font-family: 'Doppio one';
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  position: relative;
  top: 25.5px;
}

.cf {
  clear: both;
}

#navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
}

#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  color: rgb(204, 153, 0);
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
}

#clock {
  font-family: Rajdhani;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}


/*MARGIN ADDED HERE*/

.cf li {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Language And Resource Imports -->
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Doppio+One|Rajdhani|Quicksand|Raleway&effect=shadow-mutliple|outline">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
<script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>JF Web | Page 1</title>

</head>

<header>
  <div id="titlebar">
    <div id="logotext">
      <h1>JF Web &copy;</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul id="navbar" class="cf">
        <li><a href="Index.html" class="active">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<body onload="mainClock()">
  <span id="clock"></span>
</body>

</html>
```